# How to convert 3 digits integer to datetime in specific format?

Tags: c#

My current problem is when I got 3 digits from database.

Example: int digit = 650. What I need is to convert this 3 digit number into time like 6:30 AM/PM.

I already tried `DateTime.ParseExact`, but my string wasn't recognized as valid type of DateTime.

This is my code what I already tried.

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(string.Format("{0}", InternalLoadingListS3Item.U_CAS_NAKL.ToString()), "HHmm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I just want to convert this 3 digit number into specific time format: 6:30 for example.

Comment: how would be 12:30 looks with "3 digit" ?

Comment: The first thing you need to do is fix your database.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We'll need some more information in order to help you. Is 650 meant to be 6:30 AM or 6:30 PM? It can't be both. How would (say) 3:25PM be represented? Note that you won't be able to use `DateTime.Parse` as that isn't a regular date/time format. My guess is that you'll need to parse it from an integer and go from there, but we'll need more information first.

Comment: @MarkBenningfield I can´t do anything with that database. It isn´t mine. I have only select queries at my disposal.

Comment: @JonSkeet Well it will depend if it´s day or evening :)

Comment: Without more context, there are too many ambiguous interpretations of too many values.

Comment: @Azgraloth: So are you saying your database value doesn't actually represent a time of day, but a time of *half* day? That doesn't sound terribly useful.

Comment: Agreed with @Selvin's question - Please give us some examples of inputs and expected outputs such as 12:30AM, 11:51PM, etc...

Comment: @Selvin It depends. I sometimes get 3 digits like 650, which will look 6:50 or 4 digits number 1230 which will look as 12:30. :)

Comment: @JonSkeet I just get number in integer type. In client side i convert in to string and then to the specified datetime.

Comment: @JohnBustos Well. I get from database 3 digit number or 4 digit number. If I get number for example 650 - I need it looks like 6:50. If I get 1230 - it will look like 12:30.

Comment: but in the question you wrote that 650 is 6:30 not 6:50 ..

Comment: @Selvin Sorry, that was my bad. It will be of course 6:50.

Comment: @Azgraloth: Please correct the question in terms of 650 vs 630. (It wasn't at all obvious - I thought the last two digits might be "percentage through the hour" or something similar.) And it's still very unclear whether this is *actually* a full time of day, or just of the half day. It's also definitely *not* a `DateTime`. You could create a `TimeSpan` which is the type (unfortunately) used for `DateTime.TimeOfDay`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a understand well...

```
int time = 650;

int hours = time / 100;
int minutes = time % 100;

DateTime date = DateTime.Today.AddHours(hours).AddMinutes(minutes);
```

I use the date of the current day since it's not clear about that.